# Tradução medalha lengedário

Tags: suporte, tradução

Essa tradução da medalha **Legendário** parece um pouco confusa pra mim:

> Ganhou 200 de reputação em um dia 150 vezes..

Quando eu li isso achei que o [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) era um semideus, porque 200 de reputação em um dia 150 vezes dava 30k.

Então fui investigar e vi que no dia que ele ganhou a medalha ele ganhou cerca de 290 pontos de reputação, fui no SO em inglês para ver a tradução e fez mais sentido:

> Earn 200 daily reputation 150 times.

Então entendi que era: Ganhe 200 de reputação por dia (não necessariamente dias seguidos) 150 vezes. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Outro descrição de medalha que eu acho confusa é a do eleitorado: "Vote em 600 perguntas, com pelo menos 25% dos votos totais indo para perguntas."

Comment: Que tal a tradução "mortar 150 vezes"?

Comment: A propósito, Maniero é uma lenda viva. Quase um bot. Rápido e certo, tendendo a perfeição, melhorando a cada resposta dada. Quase uma IA para fazer códigos e respostas ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim! Hahaha, eu até tinha acreditado que ele ganhou 30k em um dia. :P

Comment: Além disso que tal mudar para lendário em vez de legendário?

Comment: Concordo @Stormwind

Comment: @Stormwind mas aí perde a referência ao Barney. Pois isso do jeito que é hoje é LEGEN - espere por isso - DÁRIO

Comment: @Stormwind Concordo, [lendário](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lendário) vs [legendário](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/legendário) - então creio que apesar de legendário poder 'servir', ainda sim torna o uso [ambiguo](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ambíguo), já lendário descreve bem a medalha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e outro ponto, toda vez que leio legendário lembro de legendas, e não de uma lenda. Apesar que, como disse, lendário e legendário já cobrem o intuito da medalha.

Comment: @Stormwind sim, foi isso mesmo que eu quis dizer quando concordei com seu comentário, legendário é uma palavra ambígua, ou seja tem mais de um significado e um deles é referente a *'compilador (pessoa provavelmente) de legendas'*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É um pouco confusa mesmo, seria mais apropriado algo como:

> Ganhou 200 pontos em 150 dias diferentes

Ou

> Ganhou 200 pontos por dia, 150 vezes

Ou a sugestão do @Knautiluz

> Ganhou 200 pontos 150 vezes, em dias diferentes

Comment: Pessoalmente o texto que está até nem me parece muito confuso, mas a sua sugestão é otima. Fica super claro. Não dá para recomendar para eles essa tradução ?

Comment: Mas essa versão também pode dar a entender 200 pontos no total

Comment: Ganhou 200 pontos 150 vezes, em dias diferentes. Talvez fosse o ideal?

Comment: Sugestões adicionadas.